# Struts2 tags inserting <br>

Tags: java, struts2, struts-tags

I am currently upgrading from Struts 2.0.11.1 to Struts 2.3.7, but I'm having a problem with the output of Struts tags (like `<s:radio>`and `<s:textarea>`. Before, the output of these tags were two `<div>`'s, one containing the label, and one containing the radiobuttons/textarea. But after I upgraded there is a `<br>`between the two `<div>`'s.

Before:

```
<div id="wwlbl_something_someString" class="wwlbl">
    <label for="something_someString" class="desc">Some label</label>
</div>
<div id="wwctrl_something_someString" class="wwctrl">
    <!--radiobuttons/textarea -->
</div>
```

After

```
<div id="wwlbl_something_someString" class="wwlbl">
    <label for="something_someString" class="desc">Some label</label>
</div>
<!-- I don't want this.. -->
<br>
<!-- -->
<div id="wwctrl_something_someString" class="wwctrl">
    <!--radiobuttons/textarea -->
</div>
```

The jsp:

```
    <li class="wwgrp flowClear">
        <h3 class="header"><s:text name="something.header"/></h3>
        <ol class="nobullets">
          <s:radio list="yesNoList"
                   label="%{getText('something.text.label')}"
                   name="something.someString"
                   value="something.some"
                   disabled="%{readOnly}"/>
        </ol>
      </li>
```

@Comment: There are a lot of things in this project that many have never seen before (not in a good way) ;)

Does anyone know if this is something that has changed in Struts, and if so, how to avoid creating the `<br>`'s?

Comment: post the jsp, I've never seen such output.

Comment: What theme are you using? You can always use CSS to make them go away.

Comment: Maybe the Struts team changed the default theme? What do you have in `struts.ui.theme` property in struts.xml or struts2.properties?

Comment: forgot that first time I used struts2 I was really disappointed that it breaks the design. Then I have noticed strange CSS in the output. After that I've figured out how to get rip of that CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually stumbled across the answer. As an answer to the last comment `struts.ui.theme` is set to `css_xhtml`.

http://depressedprogrammer.wordpress.com/2007/04/11/struts-2-form-control-templates/

> One quick note, the xhtml_css theme also generates a very worthless `<br/>` tag between a label and the control which can throw of your entire look, do get rid of this you’ll have to do a `.wwgrp br { display: none; }` in your CSS stylesheeet.

So I assume doing this will solve the problem, it is something added by struts theme, probably changed when I updated Struts version.

Pointers on how this is usually set up/should be set up is welcomed, as I do not know anything about this.. :)

Comment: I can't stand "help" from the themes... set the theme globally to "simple" in struts.xml and just write plain html. If you are upgrading you can set the theme on a page or tag basis should you need.

Comment: Ok, i will try setting it to simple and see what comes out :)

Comment: I know it is seven years now... :-)
The 'simple'-theme does not render labels: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19120870/1168613