# Struts 2: textbox label is not displayed

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, themes, action

I am new to Struts 2 and started to build my new application. I created a JSP page with simple textbox and a button but my textbox labels are not getting displayed. here is my JSP code,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

 <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Enter Outbound details</title>
</head>
<body>

    <s:form action="outbound.action" method="post">
    <h1> Enter required details for fetching outbound log</h1>

    <s:textfield label="StationId" name="StationId" size="20" />
    <s:textfield label="Username" name="username" />
    <s:submit method="execute" value="Submit" align="center" />


    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

My output is (sorry i could not paste the image),

Enter required details for fetching outbound log

textbox textbox **sumbit_button**

I could see only the textbox. I cant find the label. I am not sure where I am making the mistake. Please let me know in case if any additional details are needed.

Comment: Please post the `html`. On second note check if googling helps.

Comment: Expanding on Romans answer... you probably have "simple" as the default theme? If so just use normal html for the label. Or manually set the theme but using plain html will reduce the "magic" factor. Which if you are using the simple theme a reader would come to expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labels are rendered if `xhtml` or `css_xhtml` themes applied. Themes are also used for other markup injected into the document via templates. You should either change the default theme used for every page or use the `s:form` tag `theme` attribute to override the default setting.

```
<s:form action="outbound.action" method="post" theme="xhtml">
```